# Javascript: "Cancelling" a dynamic script tag?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, scripting

I use dynamic script tags to request javascript from external domains. Sometimes the request takes too long; is it possible to stop the request or timeout if the requests takes too long?

I do not want to use xmlhttprequest because I'd like to avoid having to use a server side proxy.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd assume they mean a script tag that is itself written into the page by an existing script (so as to load a new script on-the-fly).

Comment: Not sure why this was modded down, I didn't see any reason for it to be. +1 to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Having said that there are different ways of adding a script dynamically, a way of doing this is by appending a `<script>` node to the document's body when the DOM is ready, and then removing it if it takes to long to load..

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>bla</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function init(){
         var max_time = 2000 //in milliseconds
         g_script_url = "http://yoursite.net/script.js";
         var script = document.createElement("script"); 
         script.setAttribute("src",script_url);
         script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");   
         document.body.appendChild(script);   

         g_timeout=setTimeout(function(){ 
           var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
           for (var i=0; i < scripts.length; i++ ){
           if (scripts[i].src == script_url){
              document.body.removeChild(scripts[i]);
            }
           }   
          },max_time);
        }

     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>bla bla [...]</body>
  </html>
```

Then you can add an instruction to clear the timeout at the end of the dynamically loaded script:

```
/* end of http://yoursite.net/script.js's code */
clearTimout(g_timeout);
```

**NOTE:**

document.addEventListener does not work in IE, if you want a cross platform solution use Jquery's method [$(document).ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn) or have a look at [Document ready equivalent without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. I created a script that sleeps for 10 seconds, and then returns and inserted it as a script src, and the request is not canceled.